# Calculated Number of Days based on Today

Tags: list, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated date based on the number of days a package has been at the listed location.  The formula in Excel is =(TODAY()-J2).  Simple enough.  However, apparently the syntax does not cross over once the spreadsheet has been imported into SharePoint as a list.  What is the formula for this to create the same effect?

Comment: Just note though, the calculated fields are not going to auto adjust every day. They are static until someone edits the list item, or there are background processes doing nightly SystemUpdate() operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Calculated Column on the list, with formula like

=([TODAY]-[Created])

OR

=DATEDIF([TODAY], [Created],"d")